# project structure with multiple external libs

Tags: git, project-management, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a project A which need to use library B and library C. They are both on git. I want to obtain a local copy of B and C and make some custom changes but at the same time able to update B and C from their git repository.

For example, I need B's commit B1 and C's commit C1 and change them to be used in A. Later I want to pull B and C but make my changes (merge?). I would like to keep A, B, C in the same git repo.

I'm considering using git subtree, but it seems impossible to get B1 and C1 at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using submodules remains the more precise option, as you can:

- fork B and C (in order to get repos you can push back to)
- add them as submodules to your project A (which reference an exact SHA1 for each subrepos)

That means B and C are subrepos within A, and behave as any other git repo:

- you can modify them, commit and push (as long as you add, commit and push in A as well, in order to record the new gitlink)
- you can *also* add an "upstream" remote url, referencing the original B repo and C repo. That allows you to rebase or merge your own modification with upstream/master, taking into account the original repo evolutions.